# How delete class from Production that doesn't have code coverage

Tags: deployment, vs-code

I have two classes on production org that is like a default class (supersort and TrialCustomerPortalHomePageController), but does not have code coverage at all. So because of that I'm not able to even do a destructive deploy to delete these classes. I've tried to use Visual Studio Code and Workbench. This is the error that I'm seeing in VSCode: INVALID_OPERATION : testLevel of NoTestRun cannot be used in production organizations.

Comment: When you delete a class, a unit tests are run for all of the remaining classes, and there should be sufficient amount of coverage for those, which remain

Comment: I only have these two classes in production.

Comment: Read the answer on this post here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/291695/how-to-delete-apex-class

You will need to deploy destructive changes

Comment: Change the apex classes to test classes by adding the `@isTest` annotation to the top and deploy that to production. Then you should be able to delete using workbench since there is no test coverage requirement with test classes.

Answer (score -1):

http://mysalesforcestuff.blogspot.com/2018/10/100-test-class-coverage-when-commenting.html
http://carvingintheclouds.blogspot.com/2013/12/deploying-destructive-changes-using.html

1. In sandbox, replace code in class that has no code coverage with few lines of dummy code
2. In sandbox, create test class to cover few lines of dummy code
3. Deploy class and test class from sandbox to production using 'Run specified Tests'
4. Deploy destructive changes to sandbox and production using Workbench (use 'Run Specified Tests')

My class:

```java
public class ClassWithNoCoverage{
    public static String ClassWithNoCoverageMethod(){
       String myString = 'Hello World';
       return myString;
    }
}
```

My test class:

```java
@isTest
private class ClassWithNoCoverageTest{
    static testMethod void testCommented(){
        Test.StartTest();
        system.assertEquals('Hello World',ClassWithNoCoverage.ClassWithNoCoverageMethod());   
        Test.StopTest();
    }
}
```